# How to test to test whether 2 variables can be dropped simultaneously in multiple regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

What is the null hypothesis? And how would I find the t-value if I have to drop them simultaneously?

Comment: You would have to tell us the null hypothesis. @Gregg gave you an answer for one null: That $R^2$ does not change. But you could come up with other nulls.  In any case, using statistics and, in particular, statistical significance, to decide which variables to drop is not a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can assess if there is a statistically significant change in the coefficient of determination between the models with and without the two independent variables. For each model (#1 the smaller and #2 the larger), calculate the coefficient of determination (the square of the correlation between the observed dependent variables and the predicted values from the model), $R_1^2$ and $R_2^2$.
Then, you can test
$$H_0:\Delta R^2 = 0$$
with an $F$-ratio test:
$$F = \frac{R_2^2-R_1^2}{1-R_2^2} · \frac{n-k_2-1}{k_2-k_1}$$
with $k_2-k_1$ and $n-k_2-1$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the sample size (must be the same sample for both models) and $k_i$ is the number of independent variables in each model.

Lastly, if you are conducting this test adding only one variable into your model, then it is equivalent to a $t$-ratio test ($F=t^2$). To assess more than one variable at a time, you have to use the $F$-ratio.

Comment: $R^2$? Not an Adjusted $R^2$?

Comment: I am a strong advocate of never using the adjusted $R^2$ for such an analysis.  The adjusted $R^2$ adjusts the estimate based on sample size and number of parameters, but the question such a test is addressing is how many parameters are appropriate. I argue this is a case of either putting the cart before the horse, or stacking the deck in favor of one outcome over the other. One could also argue that the bias showing up in one model estimate would be comparable to the other estimate (high tide rises all boats).